# NginX reverse proxy with iRedMail Apache2

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, email-server

On an empty VPS hosting, I managed to run the base iRedMail installation with Apache2 and LDAP and my roundcubemail was accessible at:
`https://www.mydomain.com/mail`

then I installed NginX, shutdown Apache2, reconfigured iRedMail (without adding any extra A record in the DNS entry) and managed to run it on NginX base installation as well with roundcubemail accessible at:
`https://mail.mydomain.com`

Now, I want to run NginX reverse proxy with the base iRedMail Apache2 installation with roundcubemail accessible at:
`https://mail.mydomain.com`
and I'm kinda stuck with the following Apache2 config files:
`/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

> Listen 8080

`/etc/apahce2/sites-available/my-iredmail.conf`

> `<VirtualHost *:8080>`
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/
>     ServerName mail.mydomain.com
>
> Alias / "/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail/"
>    `<Directory "/usr/share/apache2/roundcubemail">`
>       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
>       AllowOverride All
>       Order allow,deny
>       Allow from all
>    `</Directory>`
>   `</VirtualHost>`

and following NginX config file:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

> server {
>           listen 80 default_server;
>           listen [::]:80;
>
> ```
>     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
>     index index.html index.htm index.php;
>
>     server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com mail.mydomain.com;
>
>     location / {
>             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
>     }
>
>     location ~ \.php$ {
>             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
>             proxy_set_header Host $host;
>             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
>     }
>
>     location ~ /\.ht {
>             deny all;
>     }
> ```
>
> }
>
> server {
>           listen 443 ssl;
>
> ```
>     root /var/www;
>     index index.html index.htm index.php;
>
>     server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com mail.mydomain.com;
>
>     ssl                  on;
>     ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem;
>     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key;
>     ssl_session_timeout  5m;
>     ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
>     ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
>     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
>
>     location / {
>             # Apache is listening here
>             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
>             proxy_set_header Host $host;
>             proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Hitting in browser:
`https://mail.mydomain.com`
gives the usual `SSL Connection Error`.
Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
}
```

You cannot use proxy_pass in a location that is not static. You should do it the other way around. Make a list of things that shall be loaded locally by nginx and then pass the `location /` using proxy_pass back to Apache.

Comment: I removed the faulty line in NginX default config file.  

So now, I get the error on the browser:  
`This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at https://mail.mydomain.com/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.`

The NginX error is gone but the Apache error remains the same.  
I think it's some config problem with setup of iRedMail.
Any clue?

Comment: The Apache2 error is:
`Thu Apr 17 17:41:19.353488 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10111] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 17 17:41:20.526067 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10199] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5+ configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 17 17:41:20.526144 2014] [core:notice] [pid 10199] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Comment: @Shah-G that's not an apache error, those are just lines that indicates the apache process was shutdown and then it was started again. By the way, in Apache, directives like , Order, Allow, Deny are all deprecated and belong to 2.2 (only available if you have loaded mod_acces_compat for compatibility, you should not use them, and probably neither you should use mpm_prefork. Also if you are the admin of the site you don't need to use htaccess so setting "AllowOverride none" would be a better choice.